# Unknown colum error with model associations

Tags: cakephp

I have two associated Models:

1. Location hasMany Sports
2. Sport belongsTo Location

In my Sport model, I am using this order:

```
public $order = 'Location.name ASC, Sport.name ASC';
```

No problem there. The issue is that when I try to delete a record via the Location model I am getting an Unknown column error in the ON clause, where it is using the Sport model order:

```
SELECT `Sport`.`id` FROM `scheduler`.`sports` AS `Sport` WHERE `Sport`.`location_id` = 6 ORDER BY `Location`.`name` ASC, `Sport`.`name` ASC
```

I have 'dependent' => true in the Location hasMany association, so I expect it to delete the Sport record, but why is that select statement not properly JOINing the Location table. I have recursive set to 1. And if I remove Location.name in the order, it works fine.

A little new to cakePHP. Using 2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the $order from Sport - $order in a model defines the default sort order for the model - not any related models.

If you need to order a query, you do it like this:

```
$results = $this->Sport->find('all', array(
    'conditions'=>array(...),
    'contain'=>array(
        'Location'=>array(
            'order'=>array('Location.name'=>'ASC')
        )
    ),
    'order'=>array(
        'Sport.name'=>'ASC'
    )
));
```

Alternatively, leave $order in you Sport Model, but it should only be:

```
public $order = array('Sport.name'=>'ASC');
```

and add a similar one to Location Model:

```
public $order = array('Location.name'=>'ASC');
```